# Change static background in tab color c++

Tags: c++, winapi, widget

I have create tab

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
        icc.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
        icc.dwICC = (DWORD)ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx(&icc);
        icc.dwICC = (DWORD)ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx(&icc);
        hwndTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL,L"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_DLGFRAME|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    ,10,10,780,271,hwnd,(HMENU)3,hInstance,NULL);
        TCITEM tcitem; tcitem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
        tcitem.pszText = L"Tab1";
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab,0,&tcitem);
```

and put a static control into the tab

```
CreateWindow(L"STATIC",L"Static control 1",
        WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,50,30,65,24,hwndTab,(HMENU)NULL,hInstance,NULL);
```

But the Static control 1 have the grey background. How can I give it a color.
Thanks

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179909 - this is for tab control, for static control => subclass control, and implement WM_ERASEBACKGROUND, example here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/staticctrl/article.php/c2909/Colored-Static-Controls.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've made the static control a child of the tab it will be sending WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC messages to the tab control. If you sub-class the tab control you can catch this message and modify its colours. Note however that with visual styles enabled the tab control isn't a flat single colour - it's more of a gradient, so even returning a matching solid colour won't necessarily look that great.

Answer (score 0):

Tab controls are not meant to be parents. For each tab page, you should create a new modeless dialog [as a sibling to the tab](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191015-00/?p=102996) and place your static control in it. If you obey the following rules:

1. reference Common Controls v6 in your manifest
2. call `InitCommonControlsEx()` on startup
3. no `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in your main window
4. no handling of `WM_ERASEBACKGROUND`
5. call `EnableThemeDialogTexture()` in the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler of the modeless dialog
6. call `SetWindowPos(tab, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)` after creating the tab page (or it will be on the wrong end of the Z order)

… then your static control will be drawn with the correct color gradient, as will all other controls (checkboxes, sliders, …) in the modeless dialog, on all Windows version from XP to 10.